# Fill ReportViewer or CrystalReport with data from Access 2007 database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, crystal-reports, report-viewer2010

So I have this MS-Access database with a couple of tables. I'm filling a dataGridView with records from a table and I want to create a report using some of the selected records. I was thinking of using the ReportViewer provided by MS in Visual Studio 2010 but I didn't manage to do pretty much, actually, I did pretty much nothing. Then, I have installed CrystalReport and tried with it but it was even worse because I don't know how to work with it.

So the first question is: how to create a report using data from an MS-Access Database? either using the ReportViewer or Crystal Reports...a simple one, just showing data so that it can be exported or printed easily...

And the second question...

I also can't figure out how to take columns from two tables (not the entire record rows) and bind them into one table to be shown in a report as presented above.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and WinForms.

Can anyone give me an advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow this link http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-stepbystep.htm . you need to use access connection instead of sql server.

For tacking two or more columns form different tables you can create view for display fields on report.

And finally you can assign bind the report data source by the gridview data.